# css not loading in owl carousel magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, css, owl-carousel

hello guys i am trying to use owl carousel in phtml file in console it shows error regarding css 
Following is my **default_head_block.xml** file which is a layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <css src="web/css/owl.carousel.css" /> 
     <css src="web/css/owl.theme.css" /> 


</head>
</page>
```

Following is my **default.xml** file through i am calling phtml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="slider_test" template="Magento_Theme::slider.phtml" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Following is my slider.phtml file in which i am calling owl carousel

```
 <div class="owl-carousel" id="car">
 <div> Your Content </div>
 <div> Your Content </div>
 <div> Your Content </div>
 <div> Your Content </div>
 <div> Your Content </div>
 <div> Your Content </div>
 <div> Your Content </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'owlcarouselslider'
    ], function ($) {
          $("#car").owlCarousel();
});
</script>
```

Following is output 
[image]

following is error which showing in console

[image]

Comment: check htaccess file is there in pub/static then rm -rf pub/static/frontend and deploy to make things working for you

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran still not working

Comment: Any one of these answers may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated Files

My All **css** files are located in **app/code/design/frontend/CustomTheme/ThemeName/web/css/cssfilename.css**

All js files are located in

**app/code/design/frontend/CustomTheme/ThemeName/web/js/jsfilename.js**

**requirejs-config.js** file

```
var config = {
paths: {            
        'owlcarouselslider': "js/owl.carousel.min",
        'banner':"js/banner"
       },   
shim: {
            'owlcarouselslider':
            {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'banner':
            {
                deps:['jquery']
            }

      }
 };
```

app/code/design/frontend/CustomTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/**default_head_blocks.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <css src="css/owl.carousel.css" />
    <css src="css/main.css" /> 
    <css src="css/owl.theme.css" /> 
    <css src="css/banner.css" /> 

</head>
</page>
```

app/code/design/frontend/CustomTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/**default.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="slider_test" template="Magento_Theme::slider.phtml" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

app/code/design/frontend/CustomTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/templates/**slider.phtml** file

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
<div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>

</div>

<script>

require([
    'jquery',
    'owlcarouselslider','banner'
    ], function ($) {

  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
items:4,
loop:true,
margin:10,
autoplay:true,
autoplayTimeout:1000,
autoplayHoverPause:true
  });

});
```

**banner.js** file

```
require(['jquery'],function($){

$(document).ready(function(){
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
items:4,
loop:true,
margin:10,
autoplay:true,
autoplayTimeout:1000,
autoplayHoverPause:true
});

});

});
```

Following is output 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error usually shows up when static content is not correctly generated by Magento. It can show also show up when using a vanilla Magento installation and is not necessarily related to a theme or installed extension.

In most cases, this error disappears once you setup the correct permissions and generate the static content for your store.

> Solution 1.

1. Correctly set Magento permissions by following the instructions under Basic Permissions Setup below:

https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001868933-How-to-set-Magento-2-permissions-and-avoid-installation-errors

2. Go to Developer mode and then to Production mode. This action performs a cache cleanup, compiles your code and generates the static content.

https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004436368-How-to-set-Magento-2-Developer-and-Production-Mode-via-SSH

3. Generate static content for each locale if you are using a locale different to en_US (nl_NL, en_GB)

example: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB

If this doesn't help, there may be an additional issue related to the pub/static folders caused by the missing .htaccess file.

> Solution 2.

To fix this issue,

1. Go to file path pub/static/
2. Check whether the .htaccess file is available (hidden file - Press ctrl+H to view it).
3. If not available, based on the Magento version get the .htaccess file in the file path pub/static/and move it into your server.
4. Finally, clear your browser and Magento cache and check again.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: still not working

Comment: @HarshJayswal have you checklist all the things which I mentioned?

Comment: yes css and js both error solved still its not working

Comment: @HarshJayswal brother your css error solved then what is not working? if my answer helps you in solving your errors then please mark my answer correct and upvote my answer so it helps other as well. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarouselslider': "js/owlcarousel",
            'banner':'js/banner'
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarouselslider': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    
    }
}; This is my requirejs-config.js file  i have declared banner.js file here but its not loading  help me out to load this file

Comment: First Add owlcarousel.js file inside,
app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/Magento_Catalog/web/js and path should be like  paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "Magento_Catalog/js/owlcarousel"
        }, do these for other js as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90768/discussion-between-harsh-jayswal-and-muhammad-hasham).

Answer (score 1):

because of your `localhost/magento` as base URL it is not adding your CSS properly.

You need to set a local domain

in your vhost file of your xampp or wampp

add following:
Note: Change directory according to yours

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento"
    ServerName magento.local
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

In windows host file (If you are using windows) add following line:

```
127.0.0.1       magento.local
```

Restart apache and change your base URL of magento. This should work

**The main point is, you need to change your URL to some URL looks like domain (e.g, magento.local)**

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/magento/ i am alredy using this url

Comment: not this. you need to use base url like some domain URL. like: **magento.local** or **project.local**